# How can I define an array of functions where each function takes as its input the output of the previous function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a type that represents a chain of mutations, where each subsequent mutation takes as its input the output of the previous mutation.

This is what I've come up with:

```
type Mutator<IN = any, OUT = any> = (obj: IN) => OUT;
type ChainLink<IN, A extends Mutator[] = [Mutator<IN>, ...Mutator[]]> =
    A extends [infer FIRST, ...infer REST] ?
        FIRST extends Mutator<IN, infer OUT> ?
            [FIRST, ...ChainLink<OUT, REST>] :
            never :
        [];

const stringToBoolean: Mutator<string, boolean> = (a) => true;
const stringToString: Mutator<string, string> = (a) => "test";

const chain: ChainLink<string> = [stringToString, stringToBoolean];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because TypeScript seems to forget that REST must be an array of Mutations. Any suggestions on how I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `extends Mutator[]` after infer. The compile error of type is fixed. But it never work as your expect.

```
type Mutator<IN = any, OUT = any> = (obj: IN) => OUT;
type ChainLink<IN, A extends Mutator[] = [Mutator<IN>, ...Mutator[]]> =
    A extends [infer FIRST, ...infer REST extends Mutator[]] ?
        FIRST extends Mutator<IN, infer OUT> ?
            [FIRST, ...ChainLink<OUT, REST>] :
            never :
        [];
```

You confused a concept. We have type first, then the value comes, there is no infer.

In your case, when you write `ChainLink<string>`, the generic `A` already assign the default generic value. So the `OUT` is always any.

Your requirement itself is impossible. If you just want to use the chain to do transform. You should infer the type in function. Also, infer the result instead of infer the chain.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrsAhsA9gJwDwEkByUC8UiAdiADRQDyAqgCoFGkB8DAFCgEYBWAXFLgEoCLGrQDcAKFCQoAYQAWiAJbEAShADOcADbAMtCrKgQAHsAjEAJhtgJk6ANoBdFoSOnzVmw5UAzCGhQAGIUAHThfgFQqsZmFta2SKhozk4SUFAA-MGxngnwSegYkYG4FCVUdEzpGVlQ9B7xNrg1tXUKymqaOnqiFKrVbRl8xBAAbgGtUCPjk8P1EhIAxijEGsBQ62gqAOa0KABCKCjaECR8BfaYW7sUHMenJK5QrIhC+CzAaHAQkitrGxuxD2KAAyl9dhc7MkMECdhQ4c9Xu8WAAiczrVGSCSWCBLbSINDQXxwYhLYBKVZQL4kDS+dAAW30FH+6zkuSaiSuziYrDGiG0Pz4BigS0UKj4sgEkvFXS0umZciY2NZGyJNkINLW9LQDNYNQA5IgOEsDWQag44ftwdtgQiIcD9kcTmdiGkBBIgA)

```
type Mutator<IN = any, OUT = any> = (obj: IN) => OUT;
type ChainResult<T, C extends Mutator[]> = C extends [infer F, ...infer R extends Mutator[]]
  ? F extends Mutator<infer IN, infer OUT>
    ? T extends IN
      ? ChainResult<OUT, R>
      : never
    : never
  : T

const stringToBoolean: Mutator<string, boolean> = (a) => true;
const stringToString: Mutator<string, string> = (a) => "test";

declare function transform<T, const C extends Mutator[]>(value: T, chain: C): ChainResult<T, C>;

const res = transform(
  'abc',
  [stringToString, stringToBoolean]
)
```